# Class with List<T> functions, only without Add, Remove and the like

Tags: c#, list

Which C# class provides all `List<T>` functionality (especially Find, FindAll - with predicates, foreach, Count) but does *not* provide the Add, Remove functionality (and the like)?
I am looking for an answer with the usage of Linq and without it.

`ReadOnlyCollection<T>, IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>` dont'have the Find's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could quite easily build your own class backed by a `List<T>` and only implement the functions you want.  This would also give you the ability to add/remove data when you do need to through the use of internal methods.

Comment: I think he meant a data type that is more optimized than a list by not having `Add` and `Remove` but still have `Find`

Comment: @Dani: I meant not having Add and Remove as a functional requirement

Answer (score 5):

You can easily implement `Find` for IEnumerable:

```
public static T Find<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, T element)
{
    return collection.First(x => x == element);
}
```

Edit:
If you don't want an exception when nothing is found, use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`.

Answer (score 3):

`ReadOnlyCollection<T>` provides most of them. You can add the finds with extensionmethods or by deriving your own class from `ReadonlyCollection<T>`.

But `Where` does almost the same thing as `FindAll`, you just need a `ToList()` if you need a list instead of a lazy enumerable.

And `Find` does the same thing as `FirstOrDefault(pred)`